# Need confirmation on a possible linker error, by Visual Studio, while assembling a Debug/x64 build

Tags: winapi, 64-bit, linker-errors, masm

Below you'll find three very simple assembly codes, one for platform x64, one for platform x86 (Win32) with the `END` directive containing an entry point to the code, and the third, with the same Win32 code, but without the entry point in the `END` directive.

x64:

```
EXTERN ExitProcess:PROC
.CODE
main PROC
    mov eax, -1
exit:
    xor ecx, ecx
    call ExitProcess
main ENDP
END
```

x86 (Win32) with entry point at the `END`directive:

```
.386
.MODEL flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO STDCALL, dwExitCode: DWORD
.CODE
main PROC
    mov eax, -1
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

x86 (Win32) without an entry point at the `END`directive:

```
.386
.MODEL flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO STDCALL, dwExitCode: DWORD
.CODE
main PROC
    mov eax, -1
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END ;main
```

I present below a table with the error messages produced by VS2019 (the same error messages are produced by VS2017) when I try to build these codes with the following linker option: /SUBSYSTEM = **Not set** and /ENTRY = empty.

[image]

I have a problem with the highlighted error message above. It doesn't make any sense to me, as it misleads one to assume that the /SUBSYSTEM option was **Console**, instead of **Not set**, for the Debug/x64 build.

Comment: You cannot pass the linker option `/SUBSYSTEM=Not set` to the linker, so I assume you are using a build system. If you want to isolate the issue, drop the build system and compile/link on the command line.

Comment: @IInspectable Of course you can. The option is there, if you click the down arrow at the right of the edit box in `Properties > Linker > System > Subsystem`.

Comment: @Belloc - in what your question/problem ?

Comment: No, you cannot. You can use your IDE's UI to make choices, and those choices are then *transformed* into command line options. You seem to be confused by that transformation, and seemingly attribute the (to you) unexpected outcome to the linker. That's not what's happening, probably. If you want to isolate your issue, drop the IDE out of the picture.

Comment: @IInspectable Ok, but the option `Not set` is equivalent to linker command line without the /SUBSYTEM option, which is the same thing.

Comment: No, it is not. It depends on your project's build configuration settings, stored in .targets files. Visual Studio's build system is entirely non-trivial. Again, if you want to isolate your issue, **do** isolate your issue. As it stands, you are just asking about an undisclosed build system, that you find confusing.

Comment: @IInspectable Well, when I set the Subsystem = **Not Set** in the linker property page, I don't find the /SUBSYSTEM option in the linker command line.

Comment: Also, what you describe as unexpected, appears to follow the [documented contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2019): *"If `main` [...] is defined for native code [...] CONSOLE is the default."* Presumably you'll have to rename your symbol to `_main` in your x86 code to get the same behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable Visual Studio ignores any entry point in the /ENTRY option when the /SUBSYSTEM = Not set, i.e., when the /SUBSYSTEM option is not provided in the linker command line. The error emitted by the linker doesn't change from LNK1221, irrespective of the name used in the /ENTRY option.

Comment: The signature of the entry point depends on the subsystem. It doesn't make sense to specify an entry point but have the linker guess the subsystem. But that's a different question altogether. This question is asking about a possible bug, for which there doesn't appear to be any evidence.

Comment: Probably because name mangling differences in x64 your main symbol triggers console mode. Try if different name will change error message.